# audio recording tool for asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

in my application i am searching for the audio recording tool. the tool should generate automatic embede code and a link for the recorded audio. is there any tool can u refere me please. thanking you.

Comment: Where do you want to record the audio?

Comment: in my webpage that is in asp.net pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing I could find for you was [Site Clip](http://www.seetheface.com/siteclip/) which records video. But before implementing this there are few things which you need to know.

Even if you were able to get a Audio recorder you will have to save the recorded message somewhere to create an embed link. This should be in the server so that other users can access it.

Why are you dong this?

Comment: actually it is our project Mr.Shoban

Comment: I understood that I meant Why are you doing? May be there are alternative ways :)

Comment: you say that there are alternative ways. can i know that one please

Comment: we can suggest alternative ways only if we know why you are doing this.

Comment: i can say it is client requirement.

Comment: actually to day i get the project documentation, i will tell u clearly tomorrow. will u coming  tomorrow.